# How to change Meta Conversions API when it's disabled?

Tags: segment, facebook-conversions-api

Looking to add a new partner for Conversions API, specifically Segment.

[image]

However, since I previously had Conversions API setup through another source, it won't let me change the source to Segment.

[image]

Here is where I got 1 server-side event that I think is blocking me

[image]

Any guesses on how to change the server-side integration?